# Why VS Git tries to commit EVERYTHING, not only changed files?

Tags: visual-studio

I changed a few files in my solution, and my commit list now consists of EVERY FILES in my solution folder, why?

It should only list down files that I have changed, not everything (and certainly NOT from the debug/release folder). Anybody has seen this, how do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Read the manual: [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: IMO as long as you don't stage specific files VS will commit all files (but those that've been ignored).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider adding a `.gitignore` file in your repository.
Those .dll and .apk files could be ignored in that file and won't be added any more. [Check Here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)